# How do I animate RRT path planner in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, animation

### Problem

I am currently deep-diving into learning about path planning algorithms using Matlab. I have referred to some videos, and I was intrigued by the animation of formation points along with their nodes, especially for RRT or Rapidly exploring Random Trees.

I wish to perform similar animations so as to get a clearer idea of how the nodes are forming.

### What I have tried till now?

I was currently playing with the Matlab example: [Plan Mobile Robot paths using RRT](https://www.mathworks.com/help/nav/ug/plan-mobile-robot-paths-using-rrt.html).

To display the animation, I made a minor change i.e.,

```matlab
%% Plot the path

show(occGrid)
hold on
hold on
size_tree = size(solnInfo.TreeData)

for x = 1:size_tree(1)
    % Plot the entire search tree
    plot(solnInfo.TreeData(x,1), solnInfo.TreeData(x,2),'.');
    
    drawnow

% pause(0.5)
end
```

The resulting animation is displayed below

[image: animation RRT]

Along with points I wish to have the nodes being formed between the points. I was unable to do so.

#### Can someone help me out with this?

Answer (score 0):

Since, I was tuning the parameters of an existing Matlab example on [Path planning of mobile robot](https://in.mathworks.com/help/nav/ug/plan-mobile-robot-paths-using-rrt.html)

Updated code: [RRT planner animation](https://bioinsperobotics.github.io/BIPR/02-Algorithms/04-RRT/)

#### Final output

---

[image]

In the code you can play with the `pause(0.6)` inside for loop where you can tune it according to your own needs.